# easy admin 4 upload field on symfony 6

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I want to have an upload file field in easyAdmin 4 with symfony 6 that is not an image. The documentation says :

*If you have an upload field that is not an image, there isn't a generic FileField or anything like that. But you could use a TextField, then override its form type to be a special FileUploadType that comes from EasyAdmin. Check the ImageField to see what it does internally for more details.*

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/easyadminbundle/upload

I understand I have to use a text field. So I did in my easyadmin Crud Controller :

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
     $userRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);

        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('file')
                ->setFormType(FileUploadType::class)
           ]
        ;
    }
```

I am stuck here. Could someone points the right direction ? I checked the doc in ImageField documentation and I did'nt find any help there.
Thanks a lot in adance.

Answer (score 1):

After looking https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/4.x/src/Field/ImageField.php

and
https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/4.x/src/Form/Type/FileUploadType.php

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Form\Type\FileUploadType;

....

public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {

....
     $file = TextField::new('filename')
            ->setFormType( FileUploadType::class )
            ->setCustomOption('basePath', 'uploads/files')
            ->setCustomOption('uploadDir', 'public/uploads/files')
            ->setCustomOption('uploadedFileNamePattern', '[year][month][day]-[slug].[extension]');
```

The above seems to work except for the `uploadedFileNamePattern`. This seems to be ignored. If someone knows why, please fix it :-)

Comment: It seems to be that `setCustomOption('uploadDir', 'uploads/files')` doesn't work. I had to use `setFormTypeOptions(['upload_dir' => 'custom/path/here/'])`

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this is the correct method to follow, and you then upload the file to a folder created beforehand.

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable{
 $userRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);

    return [
        IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
        TextField::new('file')
            ->setFormType(FileUploadType::class)
            //change after this line
            ->setBasePath('uploads/your-directory')
            ->setUploadDir('public/uploads/your-directory')
            ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[slug]-[timestamp].[extension]')
       ]
    ;
}
```

Then simply use this path to display your document.
In the case of an image, it looks like this

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/your-directory/' ~ the-field-associated-with-the-file)}}"alt="description">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thaught so too but here is the error message I got : 
Attempted to call an undefined method named "setBasePath" of class "EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField". So tried this as I checked the FileUploadType class 
TextField::new('url')
                ->setFormType(FileUploadType::class, 
                [
                    'upload_dir' => 'public/uploads/supportDocs',
                ]
                ),
but I think there is more options to pass and I was stuck one more time

Comment: Otherwise you have to override the configuration and use a symfony FileType

Comment: I found this video, I haven't taken the time to watch it all but it seems to work 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woZGODVFauE

Comment: Awesome.. I guessed I missed this video when searching. Thanks a lot.